# Split route configuration in zend-expressive

Tags: php, mezzio

I'm using zend-expressive (3) to build my REST APIs. The file config/routes.php contains my routes, e.g.

```
return function (Application $app, MiddlewareFactory $factory, ContainerInterface $container) : void {
    $app->get('/', Start\HomePageHandler::class, 'home');
    $app->get('/api/ping', Start\PingHandler::class, 'api.ping');
};
```

Every new module adds a lot of new routes. This gets confusing. Is there a way to split the route configuration into multiple files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add routes. The first one is by how you do it, injecting the routes. You can use a [custom delegator factories](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/v3/cookbook/autowiring-routes-and-pipelines/#custom-delegator-factories) to split up routes into modules.

The second is by [configuration](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/v3/cookbook/autowiring-routes-and-pipelines/#applicationconfiginjectiondelegator). You could created a bunch of files in a `config/routes/` dir and autoload those. However if you prefer the routes within your modules, I suggest to stick with the first method.

Just be aware that using both methods at the same time might cause unwanted side effects so you should choose 1 method.